# Openlayers 5 - how to set for only 1 marker with a different icon / image?

Tags: openlayers-5

In my app I use regular markers. One marker should be different.

Using OL5, how can I add this different marker with a specific icon / image?

Looking at (older?) examples I see this? But this will fail in OL5.

```
const marker = new Feature({
    geometry: new Point(fromLonLat([0 + mylongitude, 0 + (mylatitude)]))
});
marker.setStyles(new Style({
    image: new Icon(({
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
        src: 'assets/images/guestimate_red_hair.png'
    }))
}));
this.vectorLayer.getSource().addFeature(marker);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use icon style  for that .

```
    var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Icon(({
        anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
        scale:0.15,
        opacity: 0.75,
        src: 'assets/images/guestimate_red_hair.png'
      }))
    });
marker.setStyle(iconStyle)
```

check out this https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_Image-ImageStyle.html

make sure  that 
image url is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps!